# how to check whether a string matches a particular like pattern in a string which contains multiple like patterns

Tags: sql, database, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

i have a scenario in TERADATA like,

Table 1 - col1- 'XYZ1234'

And  table containing multiple pattern is like
Table 2- col1 -   ' XY12%,  XYZ%, ABC℅'

Note- the above value is a complete string in a single Row's particular column.

.

So here if here we require to do something like

Table1.Col1 Like Any (Table2.col1)  = true(1). 
As per above scenario it should be true as table 1 col1 has value XYZ1234 which is matching to second pattern if table2 col1 XYZ%.

Can any one please help me with this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest keeping the following for the second table:

```
col1
XY12
XYZ
ABC
```

Then, you may build a dynamic `LIKE` expression as follows:

```
SELECT t1.Col1
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.Col1 LIKE t2.Col1 || '%';
```

I suggest not storing the wildcard `%` operator in your table, because it is redundant information and also not part of the actual data.

Note that if there could be more than one match for each `Col1` value in the first table, my join could return duplicates.  Using `SELECT DISTINCT` would be one way to get around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Teradata actually supports `col1 like any (select col1 from ...)`, but you need to normalize your input data. If you can't store the data as Tim suggested you can do it on the fly using the table function `StrTok_Split_To_Table`:

```
WITH cte AS 
  ( 
    SELECT 1 AS inkey -- needed as input for the table function, can be a column
      ,col1 FROM t2
  )
SELECT * FROM t1
WHERE col1 LIKE ANY 
 (
   SELECT trim(token) -- to remove leading spaces (could be done also using both ' ,' as split character)
   FROM TABLE (StrTok_Split_To_Table(cte.inkey, cte.col1, ',' )
               RETURNS (outkey INTEGER,
                        tokennum INTEGER,
                        token VARCHAR(40) CHARACTER SET Unicode)
              ) AS d 
 )
```